# How to generate a random 10 digit in Karate DSL feature file without using the 0?

Tags: karate

```
* def random_number =
"""
function(s) {
  var randomInt2 = Math.random().toFixed(s).split('.')[1];
  var randomNum = randomInt2;
  return randomNum;
}
"""
```

I can generate a 10 digit number by calling this method, but I don't want 0 to be there in the generated number. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
* def random = function(){ var temp = ''; karate.repeat(10, function(){ temp += Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 }); return temp; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Peter